# Extract similar lines from multiple files in folder

Tags: python, regex, text, awk, sed

I have a directory with about 30 Python files with a similar pattern, something like this:

```
import stuff

class BarFoo001(BarFooBase):

    info = self.info
    description = 'here's the stuff I want'
    IS_CRITICAL = true

    def method(sdf):
        etc...
```

I'd like to extract from each file just the lines with class name and description (just text as a reference, I don't need a working Python file).

My first thought was to do this with shell tools. I used `cat *.py > all.py`, and then tried to `sed -i -e 's/BarFooBase\(.*\)IS_CRITICAL/\1/' all.py`, but this seemed to have no effect. I've also tried using RegEx in my IDE and finally in Python (`re.sub('IS_CRITICAL[^>]+\nclass Bar', '', my_string)`), but none of these gave me my desired results. What's wrong with my Regex? Also, is there a simpler way to do this that I'm missing?

Here would be a good enough output:

> class BarFoo001(BarFooBase):
>
> info = self.info
>      description = 'here's the stuff I want'
>      IS_CRITICAL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed, you can use address range to output blocks of line:

```
sed -n '/^[[:blank:]]*class[[:blank:]]/,/IS_CRITICAL/p' file.py
```

**Edit:**

Added `[[:blank:]]` before and after `class` to match only class definitions preceded by zero or more space or tab.

Comment: Another great thing about this is that I could swap `description` for `IS_CRITICAL` and get the exact line I wanted, which the other answers don't allow

Answer (score 1):

Try this, see if the results are what you want (GNU awk):

```
awk '/IS_CRITICAL/{sub(/IS_CRITICAL.*/,"IS_CRITICAL");print "class " $0}' RS="class " all.py
```

Comment: thanks, almost there! but it returns just `class     IS_CRITICAL` without the middle text (which is what I actually need, in fact I don't need the delineating strings)

Comment: now it prints `class ountReasons.REASON X
class ountReasons.REASON Y
    IS_CRITICAL` etc... is it just printing `class ` before each line?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. It should run in all kind of `awk` versions though couldn't test in all versions or different O.S systems.

```
awk '
{
  sub(/^ +/,"")
}
/class/{
  found=1
}
/IS_CRITICAL/ && found{
  sub(/ =.*/,"")
  print
  found=""
}
found
'  Input_file
```

Comment: @Josh Friedlander, could you please check above too once and let us know please.

Comment: It works - gives the same output as SLePort's answer using `sed`. Thanks!

Comment: @Ed Morton, So used `found` variable(in place of my old habbit `flag`) as per your nice advice, please keep correcting me wherever you see improvements, cheers.

Comment: @EdMorton, I always get confuse in this file opening error, thanks for clarifying it, will make a note of it. Changed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl one-liner

```
 perl -0777 -ne ' while( /(\bclass\s*.+?IS_CRITICAL)/gs ) { print "$1\n" } '
```

with inputs:

```
$ cat josh.py
import stuff

class BarFoo001(BarFooBase):

    info = self.info
    description = 'here's the stuff I want'
    IS_CRITICAL = true

    def method(sdf):
        etc...
    def method2(fddf):
        print
$ perl -0777 -ne ' while( /(\bclass\s*.+?IS_CRITICAL)/gs ) { print "$1\n" } ' josh.py
class BarFoo001(BarFooBase):

    info = self.info
    description = 'here's the stuff I want'
    IS_CRITICAL
$
```

For searching multiple files, you can use

```
perl -0777 -ne ' while( /(\bclass\s*.+?IS_CRITICAL)/gs ) { print "$ARGV:$1\n" } ' *py
```

Comment: Yes.. when you want to match across lines, /s modifier will do the stuff.. you can pass multiple files to the script as well.. like *py

Comment: I'd might use a different word than "incredible" for a programming language that I find incomprehensible. Join the club though - https://www.zoitz.com/archives/13.

Comment: @Ed, that's only starting trouble.. I wish you could try

Comment: I just find it frustrating to hear people be in awe of code they can't understand instead of expressing their horror of it. You get the same response to convoluted sed scripts.  I personally haven't found a use for perl yet but when one comes up I'll give it a try. Actually I think I DID find a use for it one time when I wanted a strptime() function. I have seen people write legible perl, that just doesn't seem to be the idiomatic norm.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -E '^[[:space:]]*(class|description)[[:space:]]' file
class BarFoo001(BarFooBase):
    description = 'here's the stuff I want'

$ awk 'sub(/^[[:space:]]*(class|description =)[[:space:]]+/,"")' file
BarFoo001(BarFooBase):
'here's the stuff I want'
```

Comment: That's great, and it removes the blank lines as well